# Logic: Else Symbol

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is there a mathematical symbol to represent "else"; the way it's used in computer science and propositional logic? Is it simply "or"?

Comment: No, because "or" is not exclusive. The programming construct "if A, then B; else C" is not a primitive connective of propositional logic. It must be $(A \to B) \land (\lnot A \to C)$.

Comment: It's also $(A \land B) \lor (\lnot A \land C)$, so you can write it as a disjunction but you've got to guard both disjuncts. (So unlike the programming language construct, you have to write $A$ twice.)

Comment: Here is the symbol I use for "else": $$\mathrm{else}$$

Comment: Appreciate the input. Would be good to develop some of these comments into answers.

Answer (score 6):

The closest thing to an "else" comes with piecewise defined functions, which is in act the very application of `else` in programming:

```
function max(x,y) {
  if (x > y) then
     return x
  else
     return y
  end if
}
```

would match the piecewise definition
$$ \max\{x,y\}:=\begin{cases}x&\text{if }x>y\\y&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Note that one commonly embeds natural language into such definitions, for the sake of readability.